# Accordion Experiencing jQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

I am currently working on a HTML dropdown with Accordion & jQuery. For example in the snippet below, I have AU Controls with different levels. I want to organize parent rows with the level rank, and then the appropriate controls under each Level Parent row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.accordion').accordion();

  /* Alternative way to change color of accordion */
  //$(".drop").css("color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
/* this doesn't work*/

.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title,
.ui.styled.accordion .title {
  color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title,
.ui.styled.accordion .title:hover {
  color: #f2711c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.css">


<div class="ui stackable grid container">
  <div class="one column row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui styled accordion">
        <!-- Accordion parent -->
        <div class="title"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>Level 2</div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="ui divider"></div>
          <div class="ui stackable grid container">
            <div class="three column row">
              <div class="column">
                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                  <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.041 Ensure that the actions of individual system users can be uniquely traced to those users so they can be held accountable for their actions.</div>
                  <div class="content">
                    hi
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                  <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.042 Create and retain system audit logs and records to the extent needed to enable the monitoring, analysis, investigation, and reporting of unlawful or unauthorized system activity.</div>
                  <div class="content">
                    hi
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                  <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.043 Provide a system capability that compares and synchronizes internal system clocks with an authoritative source to generate time stamps for audit records.</div>
                  <div class="content">
                    hi
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                  <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.044 Review audit logs.</div>
                  <div class="content">
                    hi
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have figured out the nesting issue and was able to fix that. Now the issues I am having, is what I presume to be with the jQuery. When I run my test case in JSFiddle, the parent row opens, and contains all of the correct child rows that I wanted in it. When I try to open the child rows, they open for a half a second, then immediately collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after testning and reading the documentation, I found the problem.
You are bounding multiple nested divs with `accordion`

Now lets see your html and try to figure out the problem.

This is your original Html

```
<div class="ui stackable grid container">
                    <div class="one column row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="ui styled accordion"> <!-- Accordion parent -->
                                <div class="title"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>Level 2</div>       
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="three column row">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.041 Ensure that the actions of individual system users can be uniquely traced to those users so they can be held accountable for their actions.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        hi
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Now if you look closely, you will see more then one div that containe `.ui.accordion`
which trigger the problem.

the best solution is to give the div(`ui stackable grid container`) a new class or Id and try to bind it with this id instead.

Here is the result

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.retro').accordion();
  
  /* Alternative way to change color of accordion */
  //$(".drop").css("color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
/* this doesn't work*/
.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title, .ui.styled.accordion .title {
    color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title, .ui.styled.accordion .title:hover {
    color: #f2711c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.css">


<div class="ui stackable grid container retro">
                    <div class="one column row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="ui styled accordion"> <!-- Accordion parent -->
                                <div class="title"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>Level 2</div>       
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                    <div class="ui stackable grid container">
                                        <div class="three column row">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.041 Ensure that the actions of individual system users can be uniquely traced to those users so they can be held accountable for their actions.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        hi
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.042 Create and retain system audit logs and records to the extent needed to enable the monitoring, analysis, investigation, and reporting of unlawful or unauthorized system activity.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        hi
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.043 Provide a system capability that compares and synchronizes internal system clocks with an authoritative source to generate time stamps for audit records.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        hi
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                      <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.044 Review audit logs.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        hi
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This works perfect! The only issue I am having is why are the containing divs of the parent rows not wide whatsoever. Id like it to take up most of the width of a page (in this case a SharePoint page) but the width isn't stretching to 100%? https://jsfiddle.net/tb36jsew/ Here is a new Fiddle

Comment: If I understand you right, then you want to have 100% width. then you need to make some changes to `title`, 'ui styled accordion' and to `ui stackable grid container retro` and make it 100% width. Dont forget some need to have `!importend` tagged to override the library CSS